# AS3 Multiple Webcams not showing 3rd webcam

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, webcam

Hi I'm trying to create a simple AIR 3 application that displays 3 Webcams on the stage. For some reason the 3rd webcam doesn't want to show, it doesn't even turn on the LED indicator on the webcam.

I have tried multiple webcams eg. microsoft, logitech, built in....

The following code doesn't work:

```
var videoWidth:int = 1000 / totalCols;
var videoHeight:int = 800 / totalRows;

for (var i:int = 0; i < Math.min(Camera.names.length, totalRows * totalCols); i++) {
    var currRow:int = Math.floor(i / totalCols);
    var currCol:int = i % totalCols;
    var video:Video = new Video(videoWidth, videoHeight);
    var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(i.toString());
    if (cam) {
        cam.setMode(videoWidth, videoHeight, 30);
        video.attachCamera(cam);
        video.x = currCol * videoWidth;
        video.y = currRow * videoHeight;
        StageObj.addChild(video);
    }
}
```

Neither does this:

```
//camera settings
        track_cam = new Camera();
        track_cam = Camera.getCamera("1");
        track_cam.setMotionLevel(100);
        track_cam.setQuality(0, 100);
        track_cam.setMode(1920, 1080, 30);

        track_feed = new Video();
        track_feed.width = track_cam.width;
        track_feed.height = track_cam.height;
        track_feed.smoothing = true;
        track_feed.attachCamera(track_cam);

        StageObj.addChild(track_feed);

        player_one_cam = new Camera();
        player_one_cam = Camera.getCamera("2");
        player_one_cam.setMotionLevel(100);
        player_one_cam.setQuality(0, 100);
        player_one_cam.setMode(200, 200, 30);

        player_one_feed = new Video();
        player_one_feed.width = player_one_cam.width;
        player_one_feed.height = player_one_cam.height;
        player_one_feed.smoothing = true;
        player_one_feed.attachCamera(player_one_cam);

        StageObj.addChild(player_one_feed);
        player_one_feed.x = 500;
        player_one_feed.y = 500;

        player_two_cam = new Camera();
        player_two_cam = Camera.getCamera("0");
        player_two_cam.setMotionLevel(100);
        player_two_cam.setQuality(0, 100);
        player_two_cam.setMode(200, 200, 30);

        player_two_feed = new Video();
        player_two_feed.width = player_two_cam.width;
        player_two_feed.height = player_two_cam.height;
        player_two_feed.smoothing = true;
        player_two_feed.attachCamera(player_two_cam);

        StageObj.addChild(player_two_feed);
```

Is there a limit on the amount of webcams you can use in AS3?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I ran out of USB Bandwidth, when using usb 3 on a seperate machine it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work from the docs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera()

> name:String (default = null) — Specifies which camera to get, as
>   determined from the array returned by the names property. For most
>   applications, get the default camera by omitting this parameter. To
>   specify a value for this parameter, use the string representation of
>   the zero-based index position within the Camera.names array. For
>   example, **to specify the third camera in the array, use
>   Camera.getCamera("2")**.

Comment: I think it might be something related to the usb ports... If I plug 2 cameras in next two each other on the one side of the laptop one of them won't work...

Comment: Yeah you might be running into issues because of the power supplied to the USB ports, potentially try a powered USB hub and see if it helps.

Comment: I got it working by setting the camera.setMode(200, 200, 30); if i increase the the size of the cam the 3rd webcam doesn't turn on...